# link MS Excel Latitude/Longitude points for polyline segments in Google Earth

Tags: excel, hyperlink, line, latitude-longitude, google-earth

I have an MS Excel spreadsheet with sets of Longitude/Latitude points for Start and End points for segments of residential streets.  I would like to see if there is a way to create a link from the Longitude/Latitude points to Google Earth, and ideally have the line segments drawn in a custom format?

I DID try something yesterday that worked somewhat for one segment, YES it came from this site, but to do the same thing for a spreadsheet (numerous values) would be non-practical (constant editing of text/HTML string).

Other issue:  YES I MAY BE ABLE TO FIGURE this out in MS Excel, but I have a gut feeling I'd need to put the Lon/Lat values for each point in one field (duh, merge two fields into one), but if there is a quick way to do that in order to create a link that would be nice to know as well.   And NO, MS Excel's Help doesn't cover these issues either.

Comment: Would you be okay with exporting your Excel sheet, and importing into Google Earth? Or do you want like an image type? Because, with Google Earth Pro (which is [free now](http://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html)), you can save and [import into Earth](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176685?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done something similar is to draw a polyline and set its properties in Google Earth. Then save the line to a file/clipboard. I then use the result as a template. I just replace the draft coordinates with the dynamic coordinates from Excel (or other application.) I then open the file and it displays in Google Earth. I use Microsoft Scripting reference/FileSystemObject for file IO. I forget how I opened the file. I think a similar reference with Shell object included. (I usually use VB.Net but I'm positive it works for Excel.)

My [site](https://sites.google.com/site/rheitzman/) (pretty stale) provides a link to a site for some tools I built in Excel that draw polylines from coordinate lists for the Google Transport File System (GTFS) specification. See the ImportExport VBA code. Code/tools is/are in public domain.